# My render isn't showing HDR reflections

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, reflection

I have placed a glossy material on every object in my scene and I placed an HDR in the background and made it transparent so that only the reflections are seen. In the rendered viewport it shows the objects with realistic reflections (I am using cycles).

[image: the viewport]

But after I render the image it doesn't show any (realistic) reflections whatsoever, as you can see below:

[image]

I also placed some nodes in the compositor to give it a blue background. Here is my node setup:

[image]

What's happening?

Comment: there are some reflections in your render, are you sure the difference isn't just because you are looking at a different angle in your viewport compared to your camera?

Answer (score 1):

For what you say you're trying to do you should have your HDR in your World shader, Shader Editor > World data type > Environment node (here showing the HDR forest.exr, included with Blender).  To get a transparent background in a Cycles render, in the Render Properties tab (the one that says "Cycles" at the top) scroll down to Film, expand it, and check the Transparent checkbox.

[image]

I put a pink background in with the Compositor, but if you want to save it with the background still transparent make sure to use a file format that can handle it like PNG (with RGBA color).